# how can I get the next object on my linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I have a `LinkedList` of objects in `Java` and I want to iterate through it, and when I find a specific object there - I want to take the next object (the one that is right next to the first one).

I thought this would solve the case:

```
listIterator = items.listIterator();
while (listIterator.hasNext() && listIterator.previous().getCode().equals(search.getCurrentCode())) {

    item = listIterator.next();
    result.setCurrentCode(item.getCode());
    break;
}
```

but I'm getting error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
```

I think it's because of using `.previous`, but I don't know how to handle that correctly, how could I solve it then? I'm using `previous`, but what I want is to use the current element - I thought that's handled by `.previous`, but apparently it's not.

Comment: The question is a bit hard to understand, at least for me. Could you give an example of such a list and what you'd like to do to it?

Comment: any specific reason you're using a `LinkedList` as opposed to an `ArrayList`?. in almost all cases one would favour the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code fails because You are calling previous, before even start iterating on items. Iteration is done with `listIterator.next();` call.
You can try the code below.

```
while (listIterator.hasNext()){
   // iterate always
   item = listIterator.next();
   // if found and an element still exist
   if(item.getCode().equals(search.getCurrentCode() && listIterator.hasNext()){
      // get the next element
      item = listIterator.next();
      result.setCurrentCode(item.getCode());
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listIterator = items.listIterator();
// listIterator.previous() does not exist in first iteration
while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
// you can compare previous value if it exist
if(listIterator.hasPrevious() && listIterator.previous().getCode().equals(search.getCurrentCode())){
    item = listIterator.next();
    result.setCurrentCode(item.getCode());
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest using an `ArrayList` instead of `LinkedList` as the former is almost always the better option to use. [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java) for more information.

You could definitely do this via a typical for loop or enhanced for loop, but I'd like to illustrate a new method as of JDK9 called `dropWhile` which can help you accomplish this requirement of yours:

Assuming, you have your `ArrayList` in place. you could simply do:

```
myList.stream()
      .dropWhile(c -> !c.getCode().equals(search.getCurrentCode()))
      .skip(1) // get the object to the right of the matched item
      .findFirst() // retrieve this object
      .ifPresent(s -> result.setCurrentCode(s.getCode())); // apply the logic based on the found object
```